# Putting label array to the chartjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

I have these codes:
let arr = [];

```
  items &&
    items.map((index) => {
      arr.push(index.itemName);
    });
```

This is what `console.log(arr);` shows:

> ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"]

Below is my graph: How can I loop through the object `arr` to be put inside the labels?

```
   <Pie
        data={{
          labels: , <-- How can I loop through all of the `arr` here?
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "1st Dose",
              data: [10, 20, 30, 50, 30],
              backgroundColor: ["red", "orange", "yellow", "Green", "Blue"],
              borderColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)"],
              borderWidth: 1,
            },
          ],
        }}
        height={400}
        width={600}
        options={{
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: "Hello",
            fontSize: 20,
          },
          legend: {
            labels: {
              fontSize: 25,
            },
          },
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The charts label receives a string or an array of strings:**

```
interface ChartData {
  labels?: Array<string | string[]>;
  datasets?: ChartDataSets[];
}
```

So you will put your array directly to the labels like so:

```
data={{
  labels: arr,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "1st Dose",
      data: [10, 20, 30, 50, 30],
      backgroundColor: ["red", "orange", "yellow", "Green", "Blue"],
      borderColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)"],
      borderWidth: 1,
    },
  ],
}}
```

---

**A live example for you to follow:**

[image: Edit chart.js (forked)]